# Find a <div> which contains a <p> with a given text inside

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an application which presents several `<div>` blocks, each one with a given `id`. Each block has an inner `<p name="barcode"></p>` tag.

I would like to know how to, inside a Javascript function, search for the `<p name="barcode"></p>` which contains a given barcode and return the id of the container `<div>`.

It could use jQuery or Javascript, whatever is easier. I could also assign a given attribute or class to the container `<div>`if that makes easier to find it.

Note: the code uses {{ }} for variables, as pages are generated in a Jinja2, but the question relates to regular jQuery.

```
<div id="{{ item.id }}" position="{{ item_number }}" href="#" state="{{ item.state }}" class="popup-box bs-callout bs-callout-{{ item.state }}">
        <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-10">
                        <div class="row">
                                ...
                                <div class="col-xs-12">
                                        <p name="barcode" style="color: grey; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">{{ item.barcode }}</p>
                                </div>
                                ...
                        </div>
                        ...
                </div>
                ....
        </div>
</div>
...
```

Comment: Do you want to recover the value of `<p name="barcode"></p>`?

Comment: No I don't. Given the value of  `<p name="barcode"></p>`, I want to recover the value of `<div id="...THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO RECOVER..."></div>`. so I know the barcode, and I want to find the ID of the outer div. In the code it is referenced as {{ item.id }}. so I know {{ item.barcode}} and I want fo tind {{ item.id }}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using jQuery, you can search for a `div` of class `.barcode` that contains specific text like this:

```
$(".barcode:contains(some_specific_text)")
```

You can then get the parent using the `.parent()` method-- if you know that that it is unique, you don't have to filter it down, otherwise you might want to use `.eq()`.  Then you can get the id with `.attr('id')`.

Put it all together:

```
$(".barcode:contains(some_specific_text)").parent().attr('id')
```

Comment: if `barcode`is added as class to the `<div>` which contains the `id` , the right jQuery sentence is:then `$(".barcode:contains(some_specific_text)").attr('id')`

Comment: Ah, yes, my mistake-- I missed that in your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You can access by giving a class name to your div tag and then access via the following jquery. Try this and see

```
<div id="{{ item.id }}" position="{{ item_number }}" href="#" state="{{ item.state }}" class="popup-box bs-callout bs-callout-{{ item.state }}">
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-10">
        <div class="row">
            ...
           <div class="col-xs-12 item">
              <p name="barcode" style="color: grey; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">{{ item.barcode }}</p>
           </div>
           ...
        </div>
        ...
     </div>
     ....
   </div>
</div>
...
```

JQUERY

```
$(".barcode:contains('Test')").parent().attr('item.id')
```

Comment: I want to find {{ item.id }} when I know {{ item.barcode }}, not the opposite. So it is finding the container <div> id attribute value.

Comment: Okay how about this ?

Comment: Thanks, similar to that (see Alexander's answer)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this
$('[name="barcode"]').closest(".popup-box").attr('id');